# How to understand a subroutine without argument and bracket in Fortran

Tags: fortran, subroutine

when learning F90, I saw most of tutorials or even some books teach that a subroutine has a format as below:

```
subroutine process_name (opt_args) 
  !main_codes_go_here
end subroutine process_name
```

Yet, I am currently reviewing a model written in F90, which defines many subroutines in separate files that have a format as below:

```
subroutine process_name 
  !main_codes_go_here
end
```

I guess both ways are correct, but I am curious about the reasons (or history) behind the two structures. I would greatly appreciate if anyone can give some explainations? Suggestions about any book on Fortran 90 programming will be awesome as well.

I tried both approach, and they all work.

Comment: Some subroutines work on global data and don't need arguments.  In that case, you don't need empty brackets (like you do in C and C++).  And adding the subroutine name on the `end` statement is an optional documentation aid.  There's no functional difference.

Comment: @TimRoberts That makes much sense! Thank you for the prompt reply.

Comment: Note that Fortran 90 is very old and really obsolete. No modern compiler specifically recognizes it. It was soon replaced by Fortran 95 and later by other revisions. You definitely should not be looking for books about Fortran 90 but about modern Fortran. Recomendations are off-topic here, but you will find many resources in the description of the [tag:fortran] tag, including some book links. Remember that a .f90 file extension means "free-form", not Fortran 90. It may be any other later standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is relly just one structure, describable, if needed, by a single EBNF node.

The simple explanation is that if the arguments are empty, the parentheses are optional, that just `end` can be used instead of `end subroutine` and that if you use the full `end subroutine` you can also add the name of the `subroutine` after that.

However, it is not that simple in the old Fortran 90. And even in Fortran 95 and 2003.

In Fortran 77 and earlier, the only option was just `end`. In Fortran 90 you could add the word `subroutine` and if you did you could also add the name. But in some locations you *had to* use the full `end subroutine`. Namely in module and internal procedures.

In Fortran 2008 this restriction was removed and you can use just `end` also for module and internal procedures.

For functions it is similar. Only `end` up to Fortran 77. In Fortran 90-2003 `end function` is required for module and internal functions. In Fortran 2008 you can use just `end` also for these.